# How do I map a NULL / NOT NULL discriminator value in DbContext Fluent Mappings?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dbcontext, fluent

I am converting from an EDMX using ObjectContext to Code First models with Fluent Mappings.

In my model I have a TPH inheritance mapping where is the value of the Discriminator field is NULL it is one type, and NOT NULL it is the other type. This mapping is valid and works in the EF designer. Here is the inheritance mapping:

```
this.Map<TemplateSnapin>(m =>
    {
      m.Requires("TemplateId").HasValue(Guid.Empty); <<-------
    });
this.Map<UserSnapin>(m =>
    {
      m.Requires("TemplateId").HasValue(null);
    });
```

I don't know what to put where the arrow is above. I just put Guid.Empty to get my project to compile for now so I can continue working.

What is the correct syntax for this Fluent API mapping?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I ended up adding a property/column called SnapinType and having two values for it, one for each type.